# How do I Store JSON data in React Native with setState

Tags: json, api, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to change and store the latitude and longitude results from http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/NW10AP into my Marker.coordinate state so my map can render the new marker.

Really struggling to figure out a way this can be done and would greatly appreciate any help! :)

Please have a look at the code below

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { MapView } from 'expo';
    import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
    import {Image, ActivityIndicator, View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';



    export default class App extends React.Component {

      state = {
        region: {
          latitude: 51.5074,
          longitude: 0.1278,
          latitudeDelta: 0.1,
          longitudeDelta: 0.1
        },
        marker: {
            title: 'Hello there',
            coordinate: {latitude: 51.5074, longitude: 0.1278}
            }
        }



      onRegionChange = (region) => {
        this.setState({region});
        // console.log(region)
      }

           componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/sw151pf')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            let marker = {...this.state.marker}
            marker.coordinate.latitude = responseJson.result.latitude;
            marker.coordinate.longitude = responseJson.result.longitude;


            this.setState({
              marker
            }, function(){

            });

          })
          .catch((error) =>{
            console.error(error);
          });
      }




      render() {

        return (

          <MapView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            region={this.state.region}
            onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}

          >

            <Marker
              coordinate={this.state.marker.coordinate}
              title={this.state.marker.title}
            />

          </MapView>

        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: In render put `console.log(this.state.marker)` before return function, and see what it returns.

Comment: 15:10:28: Object {
15:10:28:   "coordinate": Object {
15:10:28:     "latitude": 51.5074,
15:10:28:     "longitude": 0.1278,
15:10:28:   },
15:10:28:   "title": "Howdy",
15:10:28: }

Comment: Just returns the coordinates of the current state

Comment: I put an answer, let me know if you get an error, as I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fetch call, you can use the following.

```
let marker = Object.assign({},this.state.marker)
marker.coordinate.latitude = responseJson.result.latitude;
marker.coordinate.longitude = responseJson.result.longitude;

this.setState({ marker });
```

If that doesnt work, then use `immutability-helper`

https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/blob/master/README.md

Your code should look like this:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
```

in fetch call use.

```
const newMarker = update(this.state.marker,{
  coordinate: {
    latitude: {$set:responseJson.result.latitude},
    longitude: {$set: responseJson.result.longitude}
  }
})

this.setState({ marker:newMarker });
```

full code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/sw151pf')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        const newMarker = update(this.state.marker,{
          coordinate: {
            latitude: {$set:responseJson.result.latitude},
            longitude: {$set: responseJson.result.longitude}
          }
        })
        this.setState({ marker:newMarker });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Just tried but now get an error stating: 'You attempted to set the key 'latitude' with the value 51.462058' on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen'

Comment: Ive also updated my code so you can see if I added it into the correct place

Comment: I don't understand, I am testing this and it works without any errors.

Comment: try with `let marker = Object.assign({},this.state.marker)` instead

Comment: Nope still doesn't change my map markers coordinates. I get this error still: `You attempted to set the key latitude with the value 51.462058 on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.`

Comment: You have to use an immutability helper.  https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Ah okay, any idea how to implement this to my code?

Comment: done, let me know if you get an error, don't forget to install it `yarn add immutability-helper`

Comment: Amazing thank you so much, It is finally working ! Thanks again!